# Is requirement of AngularJS for big web based app necessary?

Tags: angularjs, rest, maven, google-app-engine, gwt

I wanted to build a maven based project based on google app engine which uses RESTful web services. So is angularJS really required in this type of project or can it be achieved without it also?

Comment: It depends on app requirements.

Comment: Let me remodify a bit.
Which type of application requires Angular JS.?

Comment: Something like a tutorial app "how to use angular", it requires angular for sure. I can't imaging anything else where angular will be requirement. it depends on you, if you wish you can use it, if not, there're many alternatives

Answer (score 0):

No, AngularJS is not required.  While it provides a [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) module that works with RESTful web services, you can use other front-end tools as well.  For example, smartphone apps written in their native languages can use RESTful services.